# `Required session does not exist` error while using REST api of Quickblox

Tags: quickblox, rest-client

I am using REST api of Quickblox. but everytime , i am getting response :

```
{"errors": {
  "base": ["Required session does not exist"]
}}
```

And i am using below api : url : `http://api.quickblox.com/users.json`

Data & header is :

```
curl -X POST \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "QuickBlox-REST-API-Version: 0.1.0" \
-H "QB-Token: cf5709d6013fdb7a6787fbeb8340afed8aec4c69" \
-d '{"user": {"login": "xyz", "password": "xyz@123", "email": "xyz@domain.com", "external_user_id": "68764641", "facebook_id": "87964654", "twitter_id": "132132", "full_name": "test 1234", "phone": "87654351", "website": "", "tag_list": ""}}' \
```

can anybody help me to resolve this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When someone connects with an app using QuickBlox, the app has to obtain an access token which provides temporary, secure access to QuickBlox APIs.

A session token is an opaque string that identifies a user and an app.

Session tokens are obtained via [Create Session request](https://quickblox.com/developers/Authentication_and_Authorization#API_Session_Creation).

Then, because of privacy checks, all REST API requests must be authenticated with a token - the **QB-Token** header of each request to REST API must contain valid session token.

Expiration time for session token is 2 hours after last request to REST API. Be aware about it. If you will perform query with expired token - you will receive error '**Required session does not exist**'. In this case you have to recreate a session token.

Each REST API response contains header '**QB-Token-ExpirationDate**' which contains session token expiration date.

Comment: Thanks. i need to create session first.